# Best way to add a stylesheet using Javascript for style switcher?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I'm working on a style switcher for my site. I was able to get it to work with `.append()` and `if and else` statement. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<select name="active_style" id="lol" class="dropdownselect" >
    <option value="default" selected="selected">Default</option>
    <option value="dark" selected="selected">Dark</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var item = window.localStorage.getItem('active_style');
    $('select[name=active_style]').val(item);

    $('select[name=active_style]').change(function() {
       window.localStorage.setItem('active_style', $(this).val());
    });

    if (item == "dark") {
        $("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="gdgt-dark" href="LINK");
    };
});
```

Now, the above code works. But when I load the page, it takes a bit of time to load the CSS for some reason and as a result of this, user can see the light (default) CSS. Is there any way to add the CSS so that it loads before loading the page which is fast and better?

Please help.

Comment: don't put the `$("head").append(` part in `document.ready`, just straight in the body, preferably the first thing in the body. Potentially you could also hide the body content initially

Answer (score 1):

Don't use jQuery for this, it need some time to load.
Pure JS will be a lot quicker:

```
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var link= document.createElement('link');
link.type= 'text/css';
link.rel= 'stylesheet';
link.href= 'style.css';
head.appendChild(link);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it didn't work. Here is the code that I put after my `<head>`: https://pastee.org/8bzrr

Comment: Sorry, for `link` tag you need `href`, not `src`. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have answered your question yourself. You want to load CSS file asyncronously.

1) You can do so using a loadCSSPlugin made by Filament Group. Here is the link of the article which explains how you can use this plugin (http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/loading-css-asynchronously/7104).

2) There is another way also if you do not want to use this plugin. You can put a time delay in your load function and show a loading icon. (Changing CSS....)

3) You can also load your CSS file using AJAX. Here you can find how (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp). You can also do post processing in the `success` method of ajax (http://deano.me/2012/09/jquery-load-css-with-ajax-all-browsers/).